# How to show Jquery UI Dialog on parent window outside iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't seem to find the correct solution using the parent trick to show the jquery ui dialog box on top of the iframe.

This is my actual sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/NZ3eH/2/

**PARENT:**

A div is loading an iframe on the parent page

```
<div>
    <iframe src="http://labs.**/jquery/dialog.html" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

**IFRAME**

And the JS on dialog.html

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#create" ).parent().click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

All the JS is inside the iframe.

Is it possible to get the dialog box to show on top of the iframe? It seems locked on it.

Answer (score 2):

try with following code

```
 $( "#create" ).click(function() {
    parent.$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );
});

parent.$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 140,
  modal: true
});
```

Comment: I tried to modify it, and the error is now.. Error: Permission denied to access property '$'
[Break On This Error]  

parent.$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );

Comment: Ok..are you basically want to open dialog within parent page on click of button within child page .?